# Multicolumn Styling

Tags: multicol

I want to achieve something like this:
[image]
Here the various versions of windows need to be in bullet-ed format. I have used the `multicols` package to achieve a bit of this. The MWE is as follows :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test:
\begin{multicols}{2}
Windows
\columnbreak
Windows XP \\
Windows Vista \\
Windows 7 \\
Windows 8.1
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, the distance between the `item` **test** and **Windows** need to be reduced

Comment: My suggestion would be to use tabular structure for this. But it would not allow breaking across the page boundary. Is that an option?

Comment: Ya @Werner. No need to break across pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following might be sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test:

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|X@{}}
        \raggedleft Windows &
        \textbullet~Windows XP \par
        \textbullet~Windows Vista \par
        \textbullet~Windows 7 \par
        \textbullet~Windows 8.1
    \end{tabularx}

    \item Test:

    \begin{tabular}{@{}r|l@{}}
        Windows
        & \textbullet~Windows XP \\
        & \textbullet~Windows Vista \\
        & \textbullet~Windows 7 \\
        & \textbullet~Windows 8.1
    \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also automate the insertion of `\textbullet` if you need to using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array).